# Download and Update Ubuntu softwares after installation without internet connection?

Tags: software-installation, update-manager

I installed Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS version. At installation procedure I turned off Wifi (Internet connection) because of my low speed Internet connection. On the other hand I know at installation procedure, some updates and changes get from Internet and consequently I don't have those parts.
I want to know, how I can get those updates and softwares ?
guide me with address and procedure to do that, please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Connect to the internet, open a terminal window <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and enter the commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo reboot
```